# Azure Service Bus: Application status code: 413 App status msg: The maximum message size quota for outgoing messages (1114112) has been exceeded

Tags: azure, boomi

I am using the Boomi platform to send messages to the Azure service bus queue and using the premium tier with the below snapshot configuration.

When sending message size larger than 1MB size, getting message limit error .":

`Application status code: 413 Application status message: The maximum message size quota for outgoing messages (1114112) has been exceeded. TrackingId:fb7c0a2e-2280-4401-815c-fc33dabba1bc_G2S1, SystemTracker:testasbp:Queue:testq, Timestamp:2022-02-26T16:33:13`"

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions on this post

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Please provide your suggestions on how you fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check the  few steps and references if they can help.**

- > Applications are allowed by Service Bus messaging services (queues & topics/subscriptions) to send messages of size up to `256 KB` (Standard tier) or `100 MB` (premium tier) - You're using the Premium tier!

When you're dealing with larger Service Bus Messages, several approaches discussed like ***Use Optimal serialization***, Use the ***Claim Check Pattern***, Choosing ***Messaging Service*** and ***Persistent store***, etc. along with their pros and cons. Please check the blog post reference given in this ***[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq#how-to-handle-messages-of-size---1-mb-).***

- Though your namespace belongs to Premium, there's a chance that your namespace had a problem with that entity like application has exceeded the maximum number of connections to a namespace so that we get the **QuotaExceededException** as specified in this ***[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#namespaces)*** and given troubleshooting steps like:

When the Quota (Entity Max Size or other Connection etc.) allocated to the Entity has exceeded. Callers should review the error message to determine which of the Quotas has been exceeded and take the necessary action.

**- Try to recreate it or use the tracking code you were given to open a support case with Azure.**

Comment: Thanks for your time Hari, I am still confused when we are using premium tier with message size 100mb and unable to send more than 1mb of json valid message. Sure we will open case with azure.

Comment: Even we tried to send same data  from standalone azure portal as well still it is giving error.