# A request has exceeded the maximum message size for the Azure Service bus Namespace and Queue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have configured the Azure Logic App to send messages to the Azure Service Bus Queue, and I created the Azure Service Bus with a **premium tier** and set the Max Message Size to **100 MB**.

Whenever I am trying to send more than the 1 MB size of message to the Azure Service Bus Queue from the Azure Logic App, it gives the following error:

```
{

  "status": 400,

  "message": "A request has exceeded the maximum message size for 'xxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net' Service Bus namespace and 'xxxx-queue' entity. Validate the content size before retrying.",

  

"error": {

    "message": "A request has exceeded the maximum message size for 'xxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net' Service Bus namespace and 'xxxx-queue' entity. Validate the content size before retrying."

  },

  "source": "servicebus-scus.azconn-scus-001.p.azurewebsites.net"

}
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71279016/azure-service-bus-application-status-code-413-app-status-msg-the-maximum-mess) Stack overflow question before posting it here. In this, they mentioned different approaches that need to be used to support larger messages. But I don’t want to use any custom approach or logic for sending larger messages to the Azure Service Bus Queue. I want to utilize the premium tier feature of the Azure Service Bus Queue.

Can anyone suggest me why the Azure Service Bus does not allow more than 1 MB of message size even though I used the premium tier for the Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using SBMP protocol which doens't support large messages. You need to use one that supports AMQP, then you'll be able to consume large messages.

If you want to use large messages, use the built-in connector instead of the managed connector.

Comment: I am using a standard type of "Service Bus" connector in that I am using the "Send message" action.

Comment: How to verify if the standard type "Service Bus" connector uses the SBMP protocol or AMQP protocol.

Comment: if you're not using built-in connector, then it is using SBMP protocol

Comment: I have created a Logic App with a Consumption Plan. In this logic app, I am not getting a built-in type service bus connector.

Comment: Please suggest me how to use built-in type service bus connector in the Consumption plan logic app.

Comment: it's not available in consumption plan

Comment: Is there any other approach instead of creating a logic app from scratch with a standard plan to fix this issue?